# What did I do wrong while computing this infinite series? $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{2^k}+i\cdot \frac{1}{3^k}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> What did I do wrong while computing this infinite series?
>   $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{2^k}+i\cdot \frac{1}{3^k}\right)$

here's my attempt:
[image]

What did I do wrong?

Comment: The infinite geometric series has sum equal to $a/(1-r)$ for initial term $a$ and common ratio $r$. The first term in each case is $1/2$ and $1/3$ not $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are two issues. Firstly, the result
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k = \frac{1}{1-x}
$$
only holds if your lower index is $k=0$ and you have $k=1$ everywhere.

Second, even though you are trying to sum
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{2^k} + \frac{i}{3^k}\right),
$$
I think what you really intend to sum is
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{2^k} + \frac{k}{3^k}\right)...
$$

Comment: Ah, I see! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{2^k}=\frac{\frac12}{1-\frac12}=1.$$

Answer (score 1):

Remember that, for $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a \neq 1$,
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n a^k = a^1 \times \frac{1-a^n}{1-a}
$$
Thus, if $\vert a \vert < 1$, we have
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a^k = \frac{a}{1-a}
$$
because $a^n \longrightarrow 0$ as $n \longrightarrow +\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

we know that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} r^n = \frac{1}{1-r}$ if $|r| <1$. In your case $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{k}} = \frac{1}{2}(2)=1$ and similarly you can find other sum.